# Does "setInterval" has any effect on browser behaviours?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Can `setInterval` function in JavaScript slow down a browser or even cause a browser crash?

Let's say that I have a page with thousands (about 10,000 of them) of `<div>`'s and I loop throught them and append them some HTML, like this:

```
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $('div').each(function(i, e) {
        counter++;
        $(this).html('Added contents for DIV at index: ' + counter);
    });
}, 1);
```

I have intentionally set the `counter++` under the each function so we might slow down the process of this script execution, and I know that I could have used just the `i` parameter from the jQuery's `$.each()` function.

The interval time of repetition is 1 milisecond and I would like to know:

**Is it secure to have intervals work at this low rate?**

Comment: The problem might be looping/manipulating thousands of DOM nodes, not setInterval.

Comment: Test it? Since you have already written the code. Also, "secure" in what sense and against what?

Comment: 10k divs...every 1ms updating the contents of all of them...yes, you probably will run into browser freezing or crashing.  I can't even begin to imagine what use-case warrants something like this...I can't imagine why you would even need 10k divs on a page anyways, let alone cycling through and updating them every 1ms... D:

Comment: 10000 divs is very huge the browser will crash because of lot of reflows. But however if you use fragment then i think you can overcome the issues

Comment: 10,000 nodes is an absurdly large number of nodes to have in the DOM tree. As above, manipulating each one individually will cause 10,000 document reflows/repaints. 

SetInterval is NOT the issue: all that does is delay the execution of the loop until the Javascript thread is free ... then it locks up the thread with this very intensive loop.

You need a better strategy: perhaps only update the divs that are visible on screen?

Comment: @ZlatanO.—you are attempting to update 10,000 div elements every 0.001 seconds *ad infinitum*. That's asking a bit much of any browser.

Comment: you have clearified me mind chaps! thank you, I have found information I needed! cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Can setInterval function in JavaScript slow down a browser or even cause a browser crash?
```

No. It depends on what you are performing in the setInterval function.

10000 divs is very huge the browser will crash because of lot of reflow. But however if you use fragment you can overcome the browser crash issue.

```
Is it secure to have intervals work at this low rate?
```

You have to answer this question. If you think the job you are going to do in setInterval is going to take 1 millisecond then it's not an issue.